# Clojurescript reagent/as-element pass props?

Tags: clojurescript, material-ui, reagent

I am using material-ui framework wrapped for clojurescript ([reagent-material-ui](https://github.com/DaveWM/reagent-material-ui)) with reagent for a small desktop app .I was wondering, when I use the `reagent/as-element` function to construct a React element can I pass props and style in it, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `ragent-material-ui` is using `cljsjs/material-ui "0.19.0-0"`. The applicable material-ui style docs are [here](http://www.material-ui.com/v0.19.0/#/customization/styles).

I would give something like this a shot based off the documentation.

```
;; Using inline styles 

(ns my.project
  (:require [reagent-material-ui.core :as ui]
            [reagent.core :as reagent]))


(reagent/as-element [ui/IconMenu
                      {:iconButtonElement
                        (el [ui/IconButton {:touch true} [icon "more_vert"]])
                       :style {}} ;; Your inline styles here
                        [ui/MenuItem "Delete"]])

;; Using component specific overrides 
;; (depending on the type of element you are styling this will differ)

(reagent/as-element [ui/IconMenu
                      {:iconButtonElement
                        (el [ui/IconButton {:touch true} [icon "more_vert"]])
                       :listStyle {}} ;; Your root element overrides here
                        [ui/MenuItem "Delete"]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that helped I also revisit the docs and found a solution. Again thank you!

Comment: Did you find a way to access the props from inside `r/as-element`?